# How to finish an activity from an Adapter..?

Tags: android, android-activity, listadapter

I tried with passing `context` of activity into the adapter and then i tried `context.finish();` But its giving me one error like `The method finish() is undefined for the type Context`

Comment: Use below link.i hope this will solve your problrm
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972621/cannot-use-finish-inside-adapter

Answer (score 251, accepted):

type cast it with activity.

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

Comment: You cannot always assume that the context is `Activity`. It can also be `ContextThemeWrapper`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27434760/2413303

Comment: Thanks.
The activity finishing from adapter class, so I am not able to send any data to the previous activity.

How can get an event in my previous activity that the recyclerview activity has been finished.

Comment: thanks for your help. about question "sending data to previous activity" you can use ".putExtra" like variable.

Answer (score 7):

Try with the following code:

```
public YourAdapterName(......,Context context){

...

this.myContext=context;
}
```

And in your adapter getView()

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((YourActivityName)myContext).yourDesiredMethod();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For Kotlin code:

```
(context as Activity).finish()
```

Answer (score 5):

Try passing your Activity as an `activity` parameter, then you'll be able to call `finish()` on it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

In adapter it will work

```
((Activity)view.getContext()).finish();
```

Answer (score 3):

Code for this is `((Activity)context).finish();`and complete code is

```
holder.cardUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent1=new Intent(mcontext,AstroChatPanel.class);
        intent1.putExtra("mobile",userslist.get(position).getMobile());
        intent1.putExtra("name",userslist.get(position).getName());
        intent1.putExtra("type","admin");
        mcontext.startActivity(intent1);
        ((Activity)mcontext).finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: You cannot always assume that the context is `Activity`. It can also be `ContextThemeWrapper`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27434760/2413303

Answer (score 1):

This Simple code helped me
replace Activity with your current activity name

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have not used it but i hope it will work.
use:
"this.recreate()" if you are want to reload it from within the activity.

if you want to reload it from Adapter then use:
"((Activity)context).recreate()"

Answer (score 0):

Typecast your activity name with context and finish activity

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass context object in your adapter classes.

You can use Kotlin Higher Order Function (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) in a variable in your adapter, then you can use it where you use the adapter in fragment or activity.

Than you can use your activity context where it called.

Example:

Adapter Class:

```
var onClick = () -> Unit
```

Fragment:

```
adapterInstance.onClick = {this.activity?.finish()}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your custom adapter try to call finish use below code

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

Answer (score -2):

close **Activity** form Class **Custom Adapter** just in method

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    MyApplication.value=mCompany.getCompanyId();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyApplication.context, VaasetActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.putExtra("ID_COMPANY",mCompany.getCompanyId());
    MyApplication.context.startActivity(intent);
    ((Activity)context).finish();
  }
});
```